# Extend laravel package root class without extending extending classes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a package where classes ('A', 'B' and 'C') are extending a "root" class 'Foo'.

```
class Foo {
    public function abc(){
        //
    }
}

class A extends Foo {
    ...
    $this->abc();
    ...
}

class B extends Foo {
    ...
    $this->abc();
    ...
}

class C extends Foo {
    ...
    $this->abc();
    ...
}
```

In a project implementing this package, it needs to overwrite the method 'abc' from the class 'Foo'.

What would be the proper PHP/Laravel way of doing it?

Is there a way to extend/overwrite a package class like a view can be using the vendor folder?  That would be an interesting alternative if possible.

**Update**

To put in perspective the complexity of the situation. Class 'A', 'B' & 'C' are called in several locations within the package.  I cannot just extend class 'A' in the application as I would need to redefine the namespace path to all the calls made to the class A within the package.

I am considering creating a facade for class 'A', 'B' & 'C' in the package.  That way I would be able to overwrite the facade path in the package AppServiceProvider.  But I find this approach a bit "dirty".  Thus the reason to seek advise for a cleaner implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.

The need to extend the method `abc` was to set the `from` property within the class `Foo` (a Mailable object), based on specific parameters of the application. I need to set this property for all the mail sent.

```
public function abc(){
    $this->from(getSender());
}
```

Since I am using a helpers function `bar` within the package to call the various classes (A, B & C).

```
bar(new A)
...
bar(new B)
...
bar(new C)
```

The function in package Helpers file before the workaround

```
function bar(\Foo $mailableObject) {
    ...
    Mail::send(mailableObject);
}
```

I created a "hook" by adding a call to an optional function within the function `bar`.  If declared within the application integrating the package, it will allow to perform the desired operations on the class `Foo`.

```
function bar(\Foo $mailableObject) {
    ...
    if (function_exists('optionalFunction' {
        Mail::send(optionalFunction(mailableObject));
    } else {
        Mail::send(mailableObject);
    }
}
```

In the application helpers file

```
function optionalFunction(\Foo $mailableObject) {
    // Provided the 'from' method is public
    $mailableObject->from(getSender());
    return $mailableObject;
}

function getSender() {
    if(condition123()){
        return 'aaaa@mail.com';
    } else {
        return 'bbbb@mail.com';
}
```

Hope it helps someone in a similar position.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

For this particular case where I need to alter the from `name` and `email` of all emails being sent, there is an even easier solution.
Thanks to this [Laracast post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-override-config).

All I have to do is overwrite the config values in the AppServiceProvider.

```
public function boot() {
    ...
    if(condition123()){
        config(['mail.from.address' => 'aaaa@mail.com']);
    } else {
        config(['mail.from.address' => 'bbbb@mail.com']);
}
```